# Using bi-directional relationship between tables to avoid many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

Data model defined as follows:

- Student  - Student can have many courses
- Course - Course can have a group of module. Group of modules are
  referenced using *group_key*
- Module - Modules are defined and grouped as unit using
  *module_group_key* and referenced in Course using *group_key*

  ```
  @JoinColumn(name = "group_key", referencedColumnName = "module_group_key", updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private List<Module> modules;
  ```

This group key used to avoid having a ManyToMany mapping table *COURSE_MODULE*. The list of modules for a course is set by using the module group key.  Looks working fine but following exception thrown when student has courses with same group of modules.  Means that different courses loaded with same group of module. Fetching early also throw same exception.

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: Course.modules, could not initialize proxy - no
>   Session

I presume issue with loading a same set of collection objects (Modules) for different Object (Course) for a Student. Using hibernate 4.3.10. Is it possible to fix this issue with out using mapping table? Let me know you thoughts on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a mapping problem. You get this exception when you try to access your entity (Course in this case) outside of an open Hibernate session. You should keep the session open until you finished working with your entities.

Usually, this happens when session management is done in the wrong layer, say in the data access layer of an application. In this common anti-pattern, sessions (and transactions) are created for each query separately.

Comment: But If I update course to point to different module group then works fine. Exception thrown when same group of module referenced by more than one course for a student. Thanks